# Why error is thrown when a code is put inside function?

Tags: python

I trying to write a script but I don't understand the following behavior.

Let's say I have `script.py` containing

```
import sys
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run(["flatpak", "list", "--columns=application", "--app"], check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
somestring = str(result.stdout, 'utf-8')
print(somestring)
```

And from interactive shell I run :

```
>>> import script
```

**This works perfectly.**

But then, if I have this file instead (called `func.py`) :

```
import sys
import subprocess

def GetInstalledApps():
  result = subprocess.run(["flatpak", "list", "--columns=application", "--app"], check=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  somestring = str(result.stdout, 'utf-8')
  print(somestring)
```

If I jump into python interactive shell and run

```
>>> import func # this call succeed
>>> func.GetInstalledApps() # this throw the following error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/path/to/func.py", line 11, in GetInstalledApps
    somestring = str(result.stdout, 'utf-8')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I understand what the error means, but I don't understand it is thrown.

Comment: How did you enter the interactive shell in both cases?

Comment: did you run `import func` in an interactive shell that had ALREADY imported func? if so, try again in a new shell

Comment: from comand line, I type `python`.
My python version is 3.11.4

Comment: @soundstripe, already tried. And even without relaunching the shell it seems to update when I modify the imported file

Comment: Ok I fixed the issue. I post will post an answer and close this question

Comment: The error indicates that `result.stdout` is already a string, you don't need to call `str()`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue.

I tried making this script file (called `myscript.sh`) :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import func

func.GetInstalledApps()
```

Then, if from command line (bash shell) I run :

```
./myscript.sh
```

It works.
The remaining issue to figure out is why the code does not work from python interactive shell ?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it just avoids the problem.

Comment: A script file doesn't really need to have a `.sh` extension... Naming your file that way is semantically wrong since your file is actually a Python file. You can name it `myscript.py` and it will work completely fine.

Comment: @Barmar A workaround is sometimes enough... But I would gladly know why it is not working in interactive shell.